# IBVP for the linear homogeneous 1-D Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, dispersive-pde

Consider the following initial boundary value problem  for the linear homogeneous 1-D Schrödinger equation for a function $u(t,x)$ in the domain $\Omega=[0,T]\times[0,L]$:
$$
\begin{cases}
iu_{t}(t,x)+\Delta u(t,x)=0,\quad(t,x)\in\Omega,
\\
u(0,x)=0,\quad x\in[0,L],
\\
u(t,0)=0,~u(t,L)=0,\quad t\in[0,T].
\end{cases}
$$
Is it true that $u(x,t)=0$ is the unique weak solution in the space
$C([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$ ?

I suspect this is a basic result in the theory of IBVP for evolution equations, but I have difficulty in finding a standart reference in the literature.

Comment: This is a good question!

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the solution given by Tychonoff for the heat equation with zero datum? See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356573/the-solutions-of-the-heat-equation-from-0-datum), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82408/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277769/growth-of-tychonovs-counterexample-for-heat-equation-uniqueness) for more.